# Webservice not included in standard Enterprise WSDL

Tags: webservices

We have written an Apex WebService and were assuming that this would be accessible from the standard Enterprise WSDL which is downloaded via **Develop -> API -> Enterprise WSDL**.

Unfortunately it isn't included in that WSDL.

However, when we select the Generate WSDL button from the WebService's class page, it is included, but the endpoint is completely different and the generated jar uses a comletely different Java package structure which is a pain and not expected.

Is there any way to have the web service included in the standard enterprise wsdl so that we can access it using code we have already developed (including the getting a connection using the EnterpriseConnection object)?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think salesforce allows to include apex webservice in enterprise or partner WSDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, each WSDL has to be downloaded individually and cannot be rolled up into the Enterprise WSDL.